# Is there a better term than "technology"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, translation, german

I already started quite a fruitful discussion about the term *methodology* over [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/methodology-as-a-body-of-methods), but today's topic is the term *technology*. Whenever words end in *-logy*, my brain links them to the field of epistemology, because it does not primarily care about the thing itself, but more about the logic behind the thing.

Wikipedia gives a good explanation how the meaning of the word *technology* changed in the last 200 years, and mentions the German term *Technik* which does not have an English equivalent, at least in the form where *Technik* stands for the material item and not the method of doing things to create the item. Is there a more correct term than *technologies* for grouping items that require knowledge of techniques (technology) to be created?

E.g., what would be a more correct term to use instead of *technologies* in the following sentence?

> The Internet, planes, cars and mobile phones are technologies that shaped the 20/21st century.

Comment: None other come to mind. Technological advances of the Internet, planes, cars and mobile phones shaped the 20th and 21st centuries

Comment: In the context of that sentence you could use "inventions" or "innovations". I think "technologies" is possibly the best fit though.

Comment: The best word is "technology", because it's got about 200 years of precedence with that meaning.  Any other word would not be understood as well.  A word's etymology is not its meaning -- the meaning comes from how it's used.

Answer (score 3):

"Artifacts" connotes the aspect of being made by people, which seems closest to me to what "technologies" connotes, while "invention" (as Henry Wilson also suggests) connotes the creation moment and perhaps the creator.

Comment: Guys, come on, "artifacts" sounds hideous here. Come on.  Inventions or developments or technologies are fine if (for some reason) you like cluttering your writing with completely pointless clauses.  "Artifacts" sounds like you're trying to write a sci-fi novel, it's a non-starter in the sentence at hand.

Comment: The poster didn't ask for writing advice. He or she asked for a synonym.

Comment: The OP asked for a synonym that was _more correct_. There isn't one, and anyway _the internet_ is no more an artifact than language is. It's a huge collection of scientific, technical, mathematical and engineering knowledge most correctly referred to in English as a technology.

Answer (score 3):

I would try with **developments**, as in

> The Internet, planes, cars and mobile phones are *developments* that shaped the 20/21st century.

It matches the first and second senses (i.e. count noun) given [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/development?q=development).

Answer (score 2):

**Do what Winston Churchill would have done:**

"The internet, planes, cars and mobile phones shaped the 20th century."

Always, when you write: try to remove crap.

Answer (score 1):

"Artifact" is probably the correct term for (almost) anything constructed by human beings, "techniques" referring to at least some of those methods that are used to construct them.

Just a note: the -logy ending should not be associated with epistemology (nor does epistemology concern itself with "the logic behind things" as such). Rather, the -logy ending concerns scientific fields, generally speaking, and is ultimately derived from the Greek -logia which should look suspiciously familiar to "λογος" (logos) to you. Both have to do with "word" or "speech". Thus "biologia" (biology) has to do with the "speaking" about biology, "geologia" (geology), the "speaking about the earth, etc. Thus, technology would come from "tekhnelogia" meaning the "speaking" (or study) of arts, techniques, etc. Understood this way, the way we use the word "technology" is wrong (a misnomer) or imprecise. Of course, it's the the only word that has been used in an etymologically incorrect way. "Methodology" is used to describe a collection of methods used. "Philosophy" is used to describe mission statements. Such is life.

Comment: Can you edit to fix that wall of text?

Answer (score 1):

[advance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/advance%5Bnoun%5D)

*noun*

> an instance of notable progress in the development of knowledge,
> technology, or skill
>
> Synonyms *advancement, breakthrough, enhancement, improvement,
> refinement*

The Internet, planes, cars and mobile phones are **advances** that shaped the 20/21st century.

[engineering achievement](http://www.greatachievements.org/)

> ### [Greatest Engineering Achievements of the 20th Century](http://www.greatachievements.org)
>
> #### Welcome!
>
> How many of the 20th century's greatest engineering
> achievements will you use today? A car? Computer? Telephone? Explore
> our list of the top 20 achievements and learn how engineering shaped a
> century and changed the world.
>
> 1. Electrification
> 2. Automobile
> 3. Airplane
> 4. Water Supply and Distribution
> 5. Electronics
> 6. Radio and Television
> 7. Agricultural Mechanization
> 8. Computers
> 9. Telephone
> 10. Air Conditioning and Refrigeration
> 11. Highways
> 12. Spacecraft
> 13. Internet
> 14. Imaging
> 15. Household Appliances
> 16. Health Technologies
> 17. Petroleum and Petrochemical Technologies
> 18. Laser and Fiber Optics
> 19. Nuclear Technologies
> 20. High-performance Materials

The Internet, planes, cars and mobile phones are **engineering achievements** that shaped the 20/21st century.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more correct term than technologies for grouping items that require knowledge of techniques (technology) to be created?

No, in English they're called technologies.

Any recent dictionary should make this clear (even if it also shows the original meaning).

eg. the [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/technology):

> n. pl. tech·nol·o·gies
>
> 1. a. The application of science, especially to industrial or commercial objectives.
>
>    b. The scientific method and material used to
>      achieve a commercial or industrial objective.
> 2. Electronic or digital products and systems considered as a group: a store specializing in office technology.
> 3. Anthropology The body of knowledge available to a society that is of use in fashioning implements, practicing manual arts and skills,
>      and extracting or collecting materials.

or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technology):

> 1. a :  the practical application of knowledge especially in a particular area :  engineering 2 *medical technology*
>
>    b :  a capability given by
>      the practical application of knowledge *a car's fuel-saving
>      technology*
>
> 2 :  a manner of accomplishing a task especially using
>   technical processes, methods, or knowledge *new technologies for
>   information storage*
>
> 3 :  the specialized aspects of a particular
>   field of endeavor *educational technology*

etc. etc. etc.